# Assigning a particular value to array elements

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I have an array of 10000 elements. I want to randomly assign energy to these 10000 elements using Gaussian or Exponential distribution, such that each time a particular element is selected its energy should also be shown in the output. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

Let's say, I have 10 elements in the array {8,4,6,2,9,0,5,1,7,3} and I am assigning energy to these 10 elements randomly. After that I am selecting one of the element in the array, say 7, when I select this number I also want to know the energy that number possesses.

This is the program I wrote to generate 1000 elements.

```
l = 0;
For[i = 0, i < 10, i++,
 For[j = 0, j < 10, j++,
  For[k = 0, k < 10, k++,
   Xarray[l] = A[i, j, k];
   Print[Xarray[l]];
   l++;
   ]
  ]
 ]
Xarray[5]
```

When `Xarray[5]` is given it will show the coordinate it possesses. In addition to this I want to know the energy when I am giving `Xarray[5]`, `Xarray[998]`, etc.

Comment: Can you give a small example of what you want to see (say, for a ten-element array)?

Comment: Daniel, if you will register you account it will be easier for you to edit your questions, post comments, etc.

Comment: Daniel, I see that you have already registered an account; I merged the temporary ones with this one.  You should sign in before posting or editing.

Comment: You definitely don't need that `For` loop. `Xarray=A @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 9], 3]` will do just as well, and it's much, much faster to type and to evaluate.

Comment: Verbeia, Thanks for your wonderful suggestion. I have one doubt, In for loop program if I type Xarray[5], it will show the coordinates. How about this in your suggestion.

Comment: @Daniel see my second answer which I have just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding this as another answer to address some specific issues raised in comments.

First, it is almost always true that "if you are using a `For` loop in Mathematica, you are doing it wrong". So here is a simpler and faster way to create your array.

```
Xarray = A @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 9], 3];
```

You can then write:

```
energies = 
  RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1.5], {Length@Xarray}];
```

Now, here is a very simple function that returns an element from `Xarray` and the matching element from `energies`. Notice the use of `Pick` and the pure function using `Slot` (`#`) notation.

```
f = {#, First@Pick[energies, Xarray, #]} &
```

If you know which element you want to get the element-energy pair for, you would do this:

```
f@A[0, 0, 4]

(*{A[0, 0, 4], 1.00466}*)
```

If you just wanted the fifth element, without knowing in advance what it was, you would instead evaluate:

```
f@Xarray[[5]]

(*{A[0, 0, 4], 1.00466}*)
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your kindness in answering my question.

Comment: Verbeia, I am new To the programming field. As per your program, energies are assigned to each elements in the array. Now I want to randomly select let say 5 elements from this 1000 element array randomly such that no element should repeat. let { 89,5,79,34,900} be the elements I randomly selected.Now for each element I should get the energies and coordinates automatically. Could you do this.

Comment: yes, but please ask this is a separate question.

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps it's time to read a *Mathematica* [tutorial](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)?

Answer (score 4):

Does this simple element-energy pairing solve your problem?

```
n = 50;
array = Table[i, {i, n}];
energy = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n}];

coupled = Thread@{array, energy}; (* this returns a list where each member is an {element, energy} pair *)
TableForm@coupled
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'd use `Thread[array -> energy]` myself. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for?

Suppose you have an array of objects. I have used the `Array` function here, but the contents of this array could be anything.

```
elements = Array[a, {10}]

(*{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10]}*)
```

Create a separate vector of energies. Since István has already shown the `NormalDistribution`, I'll use `ExponentialDistribution`.

```
energies = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1.5], {10}]

(*{0.0969302, 0.335765, 0.564123, 1.51769, 0.142579, 0.222407, \
0.842437, 1.35341, 0.239727, 0.0312016}*)
```

Now consider a function like this, which takes the index of the element and returns both the element and the associated energy. Notice that I have specified that `n` has to be a positive integer, because indices of lists are always positive integers, and that it must also be less than the total length of the elements list.

```
getElement[n_Integer?Positive] /; 
  n <= Length[elements] := {elements[[n]], energies[[n]]}

getElement[4]

(*{a[4], 1.51769}*)
```

Because 20 is greater than the current length of `elements`, `getElement[20]` is undefined and returns itself unchanged.

```
getElement[20]

(* getElement[20] *)
```

But if you go back and redefine `elements` (and `energies`) to be longer, then re-evaluating `getElement[20]` will return the 20th element-energy pair.

You could of course include some other checks to make sure that `energies` is always the same length as `elements`, but this should be enough to get you started.

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, it is possible that this is more appropriate. This function works out the position of the element in a particular vector, and returns that element and the matching element from the `energies` vector.

```
getEnergyByElement[elem_, vec_?VectorQ] := 
 With[{n = Position[vec, elem][[1, 1]]}, {vec[[n]], energies[[n]]}]

getEnergyByElement[a[4], elements]
(* {a[4], 1.51769} *)
```

An even simpler way is

```
{#, First@Pick[energies, elements, #]} &@a[5]

(*{a[5], 0.142579} *)
```

Comment: Thanks Verbeia, for your wonderful suggestion. I have one doubt, In for loop program if I type Xarray[5], it will show the coordinates. How about this in your suggestion.Please help me.

Comment: Thank You Verbeia. Your model Suits to my program.

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach which drops the need for extra storage to hold the paired values:

```
   elements = {8, 4, 6, 2, 9, 0, 5, 1, 7, 3};
   energy = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Length@elements];
```

Then you can have:

```
energy[[elements]]
```

> {-0.318708, 1.18351, -0.281984, -0.94776, -1.3151, -1.00745, 1.2463, \
>   -1.01972, -0.572084, 1.81867}

And:

```
 energy[[7]]
```

> 1.2463

And with an extra function `show` you can display both element and energy value:

```
show = With[{p = First@Position[elements, #]}, {#, energy[[p]]}] &
```

Giving:

```
show@7
```

> {7,{1,2463}}

and:

```
show /@ {2, 7, 9}
```

> {{2, 1.18351}, {7, 1.2463}, {9, -0.572084}}

If you want to use the array of `elements` to indirectly access the energies then you can define a function `retrieve`:

```
retrieve = With[{p = First@Position[elements, #]}, {#, energy[[p]]}] &
```

will lead to:

```
retrieve /@ {2, 7, 9}
```

> {{4, -0.94776}, {5, -1.3151}, {7, 1.2463}}

Then the following  code will show all the elements and their associated energies:

```
retrieve /@ elements
```

> {{8, {-0.318708}}, {4, {1.18351}}, {6, {-0.281984}}, {2, {-0.94776}}, \
>   {9, {-1.3151}}, {0, {-1.00745}}, {5, {1.2463}}, {1, {-1.01972}}, {7, \
>   {-0.572084}}, {3, {1.81867}}}

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll show the `Rule` variation I alluded to in a comment.

```
keys = {8, 4, 6, 2, 9, 0, 5, 1, 7, 3};

vals = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Length@elements]

rules= Dispatch@Thread[keys -> vals];

{7, 7 /. rules}
```

> ```
> {7, 0.698481}
> ```

```
{1, 2, 3} /. rules
```

> ```
> {0.144972, -0.757016, -1.02032}
> ```

```
rules[[1, 3]]
```

> ```
> 6 -> 1.49672
> ```

In the last example the `[[1, 3]]` is required rather than `[[3]]` because I converted to rules into a `Dispatch` table for speed; this is needed to access the raw rules.