# Randomly selecting elements without repetition

Tags: random

I assigned energy values to each element in the array as per the [program of Verbeia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7917/89). The program looks like this

```
Xarray = A @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 1], 3];

energies = 
  RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1.5], {Length@Xarray}];

f = {#, First@Pick[energies, Xarray, #]} &;

f@Xarray[[5]]
```

Now I want to randomly select let say 5 elements from this 1000 element array such that no element should repeat. Let { 89,5,79,34,900} be the set of elements I've randomly selected. Now for each element I should get the energies and coordinates automatically. Could anyone do this?

Comment: as per which program by verbeia? Have you looked at `RandomSample`? Also, what have _you_ tried doing?

Comment: @R.M, the one on his [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7915), apparently...

Comment: Also, it's good form if you actually accept the answer that has helped you. So far you've asked 3 questions, accepted none and upvoted none. Time to read *another* faq I'm afraid: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`RandomSample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomSample.html):

```
f /@ RandomSample[Xarray, 5]
```

> ```
> {{A[1, 1, 0], 0.666428},
>  {A[1, 0, 0], 1.26861},
>  {A[0, 0, 0], 0.643917},
>  {A[0, 1, 0], 0.114058},
>  {A[0, 0, 1], 0.200398}}
> ```

Comment: sigh... just when I try to teach a man to fish :/

Comment: If you light a man a fire you keep him warm for a day.  If you light a man *on* fire you keep him warm for the rest of his life.

Comment: lol 10987654321