# List of unequal random numbers

Tags: random

How can I generate a list of 10 random integer numbers in the range between 0 and 100 so that all random numbers are unequal?

Comment: and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/randomly-selecting-elements-without-repetition

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
RandomSample[Range[0, 100], 10]
```

Comment: I was to much focused on `RandomInteger`, thanks.

Comment: @happyfish if you saw my comment ... I'm sorry, that was unprofessional

Comment: @Young I didn't, but I am curious now :P

Comment: It was a sarcastic remark about answering a question that was bound to have been asked previously and collecting 95 rep. It was uncalled for and not my place.

Comment: @Young I am also surprised by the votes and I agree with you. I feel guilty since I have almost never posted an answer that requires real effort in this community. Perhaps because as a beginner, my knowledge is a subset of many active users. It will still take me sometime to learn before I can make real contributions.

Comment: @Young I'm of the opinion that for a lot of duplicate questions, especially from first time posters (not that that applies here), it's often better to answer and let others worry about marking duplicates. I feel like it may encourage them to come back more, and our community here is not so large as to discourage newbies

Answer (score 5):

happy fish gave the right answer, but sometimes it's fun to go oldschool.  You can use rejection sampling and a `While` loop

```
list = {};
While[Length@list <= 10, 
 list = DeleteDuplicates@Append[list, RandomInteger[100]]]
```

Comment: I like this approach as you don't need to generate the full list. A small modification might save a lot of iterations: `While[(l = Length[ids]) < n, ids = DeleteDuplicates[Join[ids, RandomInteger[max, n - l]]]]`